# connecting to postgres database via docker

Tags: node.js, docker, node-postgres

I can see this question has been asked several times but I could not find a solution that works for my scenario. Basically, I am trying to connect to a Postgres DB in a docker container. I have the container running and when I try to connect using `node-postgres`, I am getting `undefined` from my `success` parameter in my promise. When I then try to query, it says that `my table does not exist`. Any idea on why this may be occurring?

db-connector.js

```
const { Client } = require('pg');    

function connectToDB() {
    const conn = new Client({
        user: 'user',
        host: 'localhost',
        database: 'my_table',
        password: 'abc123',
        port: 5432,
      });

    conn.connect().then((success, error) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(`There was an error connecting because: ${error.message}`);
        }else {
            console.log(`Successfully connected to the database: ${success}`);
        }
    });

    const query = `SELECT * from "my_table"`;
        conn.query(query).then((error, results) => {
            console.log("Successfully connected running first query");
            if(error){
                console.log(`There was an error due to: ${error.message}`);
                return;
            }
            console.log("Now printing results");
            console.log(results);
            conn.end();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Unable to retrieve query ${error.message}`)
        })

}

module.exports = {connectToDB};
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6.2
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    hostname: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'abc123'
      POSTGRES_DB:  'my_table'
  pgadmin4:
    image: fenglc/pgadmin4:latest
    ports:
      - '5050:5050'
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
    hostname: pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4
    environment:
      DEFAULT_USER: 'pgadmin'
      DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 'abc123'
```

Error I see

```
Successfully connected to the database: undefined
```

Comment: Did you try to add the host as 'postgres' vs 'localhost' in the new Client call?

Comment: Just realized you are trying to reach if from your local machine with JavaScript correct?

Comment: Yes this is from my local machine @nateleavitt. Check my update also.